# What causes different friend list messages?

Tags: hearthstone

When I am playing Hearthstone, I sometimes get little messages about what my friends are doing in the game, such as:

- started a new Arena
- finished an Arena
- finished an Arena (12-2)
- just opened a

I am confused about why it sometimes tells me my friend's Arena record when they finish and sometimes just tells me that they have finished. **Is there some pattern to when it tells me Arena records of my friends**? Does it only notify friends if the record is better than 4 wins?

Comment: Maybe their score was too bad, therefore the notification thought it wasn't worth sharing it haha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added a comment to your question, just as a joke, but after research it is in fact the right answer.

When someone from your friendlist is finishing arena with a score of 3 or less you get the " just finished an Arena run." message, but when it is 4 or more, it notifies you their score too, so you were right !

The [sources](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/12091099005?utm_expid=68589644-24.yOgsCsWhSz-gOSDIbl82Wg.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.fr%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D1%26ved%3D0CCEQFjAA%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fus.battle.net%252Fhearthstone%252Fen%252Fforum%252Ftopic%252F12091099005%26ei%3DzgmIVOnbGIOtUe6IgcAD%26usg%3DAFQjCNHJ2A2mdNstnYioxa2DDEhQQ-sfLQ%26sig2%3DdWOY1qCu5UdJmVG4yJheLA%26bvm%3Dbv.81456516%2Cd.d24%26cad%3Drja) I could find where forums as it appears to be like that since the notification was introduced, and the [patchnote](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Patch_1.0.0.3890) isn't precise :

> Social – When your friends complete an Arena run or get a Legendary card in a pack, you’ll be notified so you can tell them, “Grats!”

Comment: I believe it also only shows "finished an Arena run" if they retire, regardless of score.